# FTP 7.5 installation package "hangs" on Windows server 2008 standard 32 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

I have downloaded the FTP for IIS 7 installation package. When I run it, I get to the accept EULA accept screen, click accept and next, and then get a dialog that says it needs to finish calculating disk space requirements, forever. It won't go away. When I click return on the dialog, I am back at the EULA screen, and cannot continue the installation.

Any suggestions, or am I not waiting long enough? (waited for about 25 mins)

Screenshot follows:

Oops, don't have enough rep for the screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up testing on different servers, and the install program worked.

I still have this problem on the one server (running in a virtual machine - Virtual Server 2005 SP1)